# custom-functions-excel Can they be used to read and write Sharepoint List items?

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

Can Excel Custom Functions be used to read and write SharePoint Online List items?

I'd like to know before I start out, as it looks like there would be a great deal of programming involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In terms of technology, the add-ins platform is like a web page. Since it's possible to read and write SharePoint List items from a web page, it's also possible to do it from an add-in. You'd still need to write the code to connect to SharePoint, of course. For that part, you could use the Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.io).

Does it make sense to expose this functionality as a custom function? For the case of **reading** items, absolutely: I can imagine a useful application that lets the user enter a function to get info from SP. However, is it useful for me to **update** (write) SP list items as an Excel function? Not really. When users enter an Excel formula (like =SUM), they don't expect to be changing any info in the cloud. Formulas in Excel are all about getting information into Excel, not pushing it somewhere else.

So I would recommend you use custom functions only for reading info, not writing. It makes more sense to use other add-in extension points for writing, such as ribbon buttons or UI in a task pane.

-Michael, PM for custom functions

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. I now realize I'm using the word 'Function' when I mean 'Sub'. 

* Creating and coding buttons and UI in a task pane - is this part of office.js or do I have to use something else like SP Framework to do CRUD operations from Excel Online? 

Or is this not possible in cloud-based spreadsheets? 

Can you point me to resources? TIA

Comment: You would use the office.js library to manage all the parts that touch Excel (UI, custom functions, reading values from ranges, creating tables, etc), and you could use the Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.io) to connect to any data that's outside of the current document (on SharePoint, OneDrive, Outlook, Skype, etc).